# Using the conditional operator ? to check for null session variable

Tags: c#, session, session-variables, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Take a look at this code:

```
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] ?? false;

        if ((Boolean)ss)
        {
            Label1.Text = (String)Session["docName"];
        }
```

Basically I want to check if HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] is not null, and if it isn't to cast to Boolean, then check if its true or false.

I'm trying to avoid nested if statements and figured there would be a more elegant way to do it.  I'm therefore only interested in answers that contain the conditional ? operator.

Any tips?

Comment: That is really completely wrong and even if it were possible, it would have been close to unreadable and unpredictable code. Just say no, man.

Comment: I think the problem is that HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] will return type object not System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.   object ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] ?? false;

Comment: System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState ss = ((HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"])!=null?((Convert.ToBoolen(HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"]))?true:false):)

Comment: So the general jist here is that what I'm trying to do it just wrong - stick with the nested ifs?

Comment: I'm a bit miffed about getting -2 down votes.  Surely my question was clear and concise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use ss variable?

What about this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] != null)
{
    Label1.Text = (String)Session["docName"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    object ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] ?? false; 
    if ((Boolean)ss) 
    { 
        Label1.Text = (String)Session["docName"]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're asking for, how about:

```
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState ss;

Label1.Text = (Boolean)((ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"]) ?? false) ? (String)Session["docName"] : Label1.Text;
```

Should leave ss with either a valid session or null, avoids the problem of trying to store false to ss and completely skips the subsequent 'if'. Though there's a repetition of Label1.Text.

Note: this has been edited to take account of the comment by Dave below.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this wouldn't compile because you've declared `ss` as an `HttpSessionState` object and you're trying to null coalesce that type with an incompatible `bool` type.

Comment: Sorry, I have my operator precedence way off. As '=' is lower precedence than '??' the ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] needs an extra set of brackets. As in: (Boolean)((ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"]) ?? false)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't do this:

```
SessionState.HttpSessionState ss = false;
```

Try putting your nested ifs into an extension method then call that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, though I don't know if it fits your aesthetics:

```
bool isPdfDocumentSet =
     bool.TryParse((HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] as string, 
         out isPdfDocumentSet)
             ? isPdfDocumentSet
             : false;
```

EDIT: There is actually an even more concise way of doing it:

```
bool isPdfDocumentSet =
     bool.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] as string, 
          out isPdfDocumentSet) && isPdfDocumentSet;
```

Comment: `bool.TryParse`'s first argument accepts a `string`, not an `object` which is returned by the `HttpSessionState[ string ]` indexer. Also, even if you were to attempt to cast the value at "pdfDocument" to a string you would be making the assumption that you would be storing a string value that `bool.TryParse` can parse.

Comment: You 're right about the object part. However, it is precisely because I don't want to assume it can be parsed that I use TryParse(), not Parse().

Comment: by adding `ToString()` now you're going get a `NullReferenceException` if there is nothing at that location in the Session.

Comment: If the value at "pdfDoucment" is a `bool` this will still always be false `bool baddness() { bool parsed; bool.TryParse(((object)true) as string, out parsed); return parsed; }` will always return `false`.

Comment: I guess I got carried away on this lost cause... Thanks 4 taking the time with me.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Session` is an `System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState` object, which is a hash or dictionary, as some may call it, of different objects, so unless you're storing an `HttpSessionState` object as the "pdfDocument" location the first line is incorrect.

If you're actually storing a `bool` in the "pdfDocument" location which may or may not already be in this slot, you could cast that directly to a bool and null coalesce it: `var ss = (bool)(HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] ?? false);`.

If you're possibly storing some other kind of object in the "pdfDocument" location you could just see if it's currently at that location by checking for null: `var ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"] != null;`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the closest you will get to the solution taking that path is following:

```
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState ss = HttpContext.Current.Session["pdfDocument"];
if (ss != null)
{
    Label1.Text = (String)Session["docName"];
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile because you're incorrectly assuming that the `HttpSessionState[ string ]` indexer is going to return an `HttpSessionState` object where it actually only returns an `object`